# Making a Wordpress Child Theme from an existing Project

Tags: wordpress

Im new to Wordpress. Ive setted up a webshop and it looks and worls like charm!
Now ive read ive to set up a child-theme to prevent erasing my custom code.

Is there a way to copy the whole project in to a Child-Theme, and keep everything as it is - or have I to go the long way an set everything up from the scratch?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+child+theme+generator+plugin&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab

Comment: see this link..: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-wordpress-child-theme-video/